# update sql cell to NULL from VB

Tags: sql, null

I have a VB page with a gridview on it.  The gridview allows the user to add a value and update the DB with it.  THe type is Double.  How do I set the value of the cell to NULL if the user changes a value from a number to blank.  for example the gridview has the value of 10 in it and they delete it I want the DB to go back to NULL.

I have tried the following but it doesnt change anything.

```
If text = "" Then
                    amendedvalue = Nothing
                Else
                    amendedvalue = CDbl(CType(gv.Rows(x).Cells(2).FindControl("txtstartH"), TextBox).Text)

                    UpdateData(amendedvalue, id)
                End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If text = "" Then
    UpdateData(DBNull.Value, id)
Else
    amendedvalue = CDbl(CType(gv.Rows(x).Cells(2).FindControl("txtstartH"), TextBox).Text)
    UpdateData(amendedvalue, id)
End If
```

This will fix your problem

Comment: Hi, as amendedvalue is a double it states Error 6 Value of type 'System.DBNull' cannot be converted to 'Double'

Comment: Edit your `UpdateData` parameter to `UpdateData(byval amendedvalue as Nullable(of Double), byval id as integer)` and it would be ok

Comment: I have resolved this by adding in `dim isnull as boolean = false` and then setting the value of the boolean depending on the content of the text box.  I then use this in an IF statement to set the NULL